# No of rows in If Else condition in Apache Spark Decision Tree

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataset of 100 records , I ran decision tree using the dataset .

```
On println(model.toDebugString)
```

Output is  :

```
DecisionTreeModel classifier of depth 3 with 7 nodes
  If (feature 0 <= 2.0)
   Predict: 0.0
  Else (feature 0 > 2.0)
   If (feature 1 <= 12354.0)
    If (feature 2 <= 14544.0)
     Predict: 1.0
    Else (feature 2 > 14544.0)
     Predict: 0.0
   Else (feature 1 > 12354.0)
    Predict: 1.0
```

Is it possible to know how many no of rows are going to If condition and to the Else condition ?

> like 40 rows are in If (feature 0 <= 2.0) and 60 rows are in Else
>   (feature 0 > 2.0)

Comment: for each condition cond => df.filter(cond).count

Comment: @eliasah : I thought of this but for many conditions I have to apply many filter operations on datafame , I guess that wont give good performance .

Comment: Unfortunately there is not other way around for now.

Comment: @eliasah : Thnx for looking into my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no magical method to compute that for now. You'll need to loop over your condition and filter then count.

example : `df.filter([condition1]).count`